# Splitting a Solana Keypair into Public and Private Keys

Tags: keypair, json

I have the JSON file containing the keypair which has an array containing 64 values:

```
$ cat ~/my-solana-wallet/demo.json
[4,182,130,247,119,117,227,207,112,73,170,126,222,197,244,99,215,107,255,202,33,43,36,17,104,111,157,246,196,192,174,95,240,23,238,206,118,215,154,238,229,96,11,37,156,123,51,223,5,231,17,117,86,136,103,14,75,95,175,132,148,54,1,46]
```

How to convert this array to the corresponding public and private key seed phrase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first 32 values represent the private key:

private_key_bytes = [4, 182, 130, 247, 119, 117, 227, 207, 112, 73, 170, 126, 222, 197, 244, 99, 215, 107, 255, 202, 33, 43, 36, 17, 104, 111, 157, 246, 196, 192, 174, 95]

The second 32 values represent the public key:

In order to change this in alphanumeric phrases, we need to convert this array of integer values into base 58.
In Ruby we’ll first convert the array to hex (base 16):

```
public_key_hex = public_key_bytes.pack("C*").unpack("H*").first
```

And then we can use a base 58 script to convert the hex into the base 58:

```
public_key = Base58.encode(public_key_hex)
```

And that gives us the same public key aka wallet address that we saw earlier in the Solana CLI output:

```
HAE1oNnc3XBmPudphRcHhyCvGShtgDYtZVzx2MocKEr1
```

We can follow the same process to get the base 58 private key:

```
KQ3cGFBdjJuRsB7U1K4to6cTGBPhgukqPgsi5pryr8v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method fromSecretKey:

[image: fromSecretKey method]

Comment: Should follow with then retrieving private and public keys from keypair.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do

```
import solana
import base58
from solana.keypair import Keypair

//Generate keypair object
key_array = [4,182,130,247,119,117,227,207,112,73,170,126,222,197,244,99,215,107,255,202,33,43,36,17,104,111,157,246,196,192,174,95,240,23,238,206,118,215,154,238,229,96,11,37,156,123,51,223,5,231,17,117,86,136,103,14,75,95,175,132,148,54,1,46]
generated_keypair = Keypair.from_secret_key(bytes(key_array))

generated_keypair.public_key //Public Key
base58.b58encode(generated_keypair.secret_key) //Raw 64-byte secret key
```

https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/keypair/

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [ZeroNine](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/657/zeronine) doesn't work anymore; tested with [solana.py](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/657/zeronine) v0.32.

Here's a version without [solana.py](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/657/zeronine):

```
import base58

key_array = [4,182,130,247,119,117,227,207,112,73,170,126,222,197,244,99,215,107,255,202,33,43,36,17,104,111,157,246,196,192,174,95,240,23,238,206,118,215,154,238,229,96,11,37,156,123,51,223,5,231,17,117,86,136,103,14,75,95,175,132,148,54,1,46]

secret_key = key_array[0:32]
public_key = key_array[32:64]

sk = base58.b58encode(bytes(secret_key))
pk = base58.b58encode(bytes(public_key))

print(pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a more typescript version solution

```
    import { bs58 } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
const Main = () => {
  const keyArray = [
    4, 182, 130, 247, 119, 117, 227, 207, 112, 73, 170, 126, 222, 197, 244, 99,
    215, 107, 255, 202, 33, 43, 36, 17, 104, 111, 157, 246, 196, 192, 174, 95,
    240, 23, 238, 206, 118, 215, 154, 238, 229, 96, 11, 37, 156, 123, 51, 223,
    5, 231, 17, 117, 86, 136, 103, 14, 75, 95, 175, 132, 148, 54, 1, 46,
  ];
  const secretKey = keyArray.slice(0, 32);
  const publicKey = keyArray.slice(32, 64);

  const sk = bs58.encode(Buffer.from(secretKey));
  const pk = bs58.encode(Buffer.from(publicKey));

  console.log("Public Key:", pk);
  console.log("Secret Key:", sk);
};
Main();
```